# Xcelsius dashboard 2011 SP5-need solution

Tags: excel, xcelsius

I have a problem in Xcelsius 2011 sp5. I am working on Xcelsius Dashboards. I am stuck with drop down combinations. I have 4 drop downs.

I want to add ‘All’ for all dropdowns. i.e.

```
1st drop down        2nd drop down     3rd dropdown    4th dropdown
ALL   ALL            ALL               ALL
B2B   North          Salesoffice1      sales rep1
Crp   middle         SO2              SR2
.   .   .  . 
.   .   .  .
.   .   .  .
```

If I select ‘all’ in first drop down I need remaining dropdowns should relate to ‘all‘. Is there any functionality/method in Xcelsius Dashboards?

If not please suggest me is there any other possibility need to add ‘all’.